# Is there a way to `useWebSocketAdapter` twice in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, nestjs

I need all of my websocket gateways to be listening on `:443` and `:3001`. In the following code:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const server = express();
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server));

  app.enableCors({ origin: '*', methods: '*' });
  const httpServer = http.createServer(server).listen(3001);
  const httpsServer = https
    .createServer(
      {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./src/utils/dev-certs/localhost.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./src/utils/dev-certs/localhost.crt')
      },
      server
    )
    .listen(443);

  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new IoAdapter(httpServer));
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new IoAdapter(httpsServer));

  await app.init();
}
```

The last `useWebSocketAdapter` overrides the first, and all of the gateways are listening on `:443` only. If I try to add a port at the gateway level, like:

```js
@WebSocketGateway(3001, {
  namespace: 'app-socket',
  transports: ['polling'],
  cors: { origin: '*', methods: '*' }
})
```

I get an address in use error because the http server already started on `:3001` and this method seems to be trying to start another server.